# How is a Kelvin Pod different than a standard Escape pod?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-beyond

[image]

In *Star Trek Beyond*, Captain Kirk orders the crew to abandon ship. I assume they do so in normal ole escape pods. But, then, Kirk instructs Sulu to get into his Kelvin pod. Since he called it by name, I have to assume it is special.

[image]

I found on [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kelvin_pod):

> The Kelvin pod was a type of escape pod that were attached to the USS Enterprise in 2263. Kelvin pods were stowed beneath the bridge of the Constitution-class ship, allowing quick egress for the command crew in the event of a catastrophic event.

My question is, how are they different and where in the movie (or externally) is this confirmed.

Comment: I guess from what is said on memory alpha their location close to the bridge is the difference. And the name is obviously in relation to USS Kelvin where Kirks dad sure could have done with one of these

Comment: Well, it has a different name, for a start...

Answer (score 5):

The image below (from [Popular Mechanics](http://www.popularmechanics.com/culture/movies/a21522/star-trek-beyond-uss-enterprise-cutaway/), but drawn in consultation with the production company responsible for the film, Bad Robot) indicates that a "***Kelvin Pod***" is a bridge-based escape pod, intended to allow the Captain/Bridge-Crew to escape the vessel when a catastrophe occurs.

[image]

They don't appear to be substantially different from standard escape pods, other than their launch location.

Answer (score -1):

Just like (even in-universe) Jefferies tubes had to be named for someone or something, in this timeline, escape pods ended up being named after the Kelvin due to the specifics of that event.

No magic here.